# Add div on every page (ngx-extended-pdf-viewer)

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer, insertadjacenthtml, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am using the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer and I want to add a div on each page..
It works as expected.. my dom looks like this:
(the div with the **class="con"** was added by me)

[Screenshot dom with div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz8tP.png)

but if I am going to push the zoom button - the added div disappears..

[Screenshot dom without div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQq7t.png)

My Code looks like this:

```
var div = '<div class="con" style="width:100px; height:100px; Background:#2a2a2a; position: relative; z-index: 1000"></div>';
(document.getElementsByClassName('page')[0]).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', div);
```

Can somebody tell me, how to achieve that the element always stays there?
(any advice might help - I am also open for other suggestions to add an div in a pdf-viewer - maybe a other module, or does maybe jQuery help in this situation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply not a use-case I had in mind when I created `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer`. :) However, I assume you can use the `(pageRendered)` event to achieve your goal. I'm puzzled zooming redraws that HTML code, too. Maybe that's a side-effect of `(pageRendered)`. If not, you'll also want to catch the `(zoomChange)` event to check if you need to add the `div` again.